# Cant find a project in Google Cloud projects list

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

I try to get all the projects with granted permissions for my account with api explorer:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/list

Unfortunatly, it shows only a few projects (at least 5 times less then it has to show). I double-checked all permissions (both in project an organisation), and in every project i have admin or owner role.

btw, if I try to call the exact project via api to get the list of datasets here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/list
it will work even for those projects which are not returned in list of projects via previous method.

For what reason api doesn`t return full list of projects? Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using pageToken to move through the pages of result. I believe by default only the first 50 projects are returned in a single call.